# I'm getting this error "at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]" when creating a docker image from a nestjs Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nestjs

Im trying to make a Docker file to deploy a Nestjs API. The Api has a connection to a PostgresDB and when i make the DockerFile, i'm getting this error at `TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]`

Here is my DockerFile

```
# Base image
FROM node:18

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Creates a "dist" folder with the production build
RUN yarn run build

# Start the server using the production build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

Here is an Image of the error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39FqU.png)

I've tried to add Environment Variable, but the error still remaining